# How do I create a metadata.json file that has multipart request

Tags: python, json, python-requests, google-cloud-storage, multipart

How do I create a metadata.json file that has multipart request using python and REST API

This is my code:

```
files = {"metadata" : { "key1": "value1", "key2" : "value2"} }
data = json.dumps(files)
with open('metadata.json', w) as f:
   f.write(data) 

headers = { Content-Type: 'multipart/related; boundary=boundaryName 
Authorization: 'Bearer' + bearer_token } 

url = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/' + bucket_name + '/o?uploadType=multipart&name=' + <***.json> 

r = requests.post(url=url, headers=headers, json=dummy)
```

PS: dummy variable holds this json file: **{"number": "12345", "name": "John Smith"}**

The output of my current metadata.json is:

```
{"metadata" : "key1": "value1", "key2" : "value2"}
```

**EXPECTED metadata.json structure:**

```
--boundaryName
Content-Type: application/json 

{"metadata" : "key1": "value1", "key2" : "value2"}
--boundaryName
Content-Type: application/json 

{"number": "12345", "name": "John Smith"}
--boundaryName
```

Comment: `files` is not a valid `dict`. So is the "expected" JSON - not valid. Your code cannot run.

Comment: My code works its just that only a portion is displayed not the "expected" json file. Maybe im missing something